# Single line printing in Python

Tags: python

I need to print:

```
print('System ' + self.checkStatus()  + 'from SLEEP ARM')
```

on the single line so it will be like: `System Disarmed from SLEEP ARM`
But it is not allowing `self.checkStatus()` to be placed in that line

Comment: `print("something",end="")` will do this in python version 3

Comment: What do you mean it is "not allowing"? What issue/error are you seeing? There is nothing specifically wrong with the line above assuming `self.checkStatus()` returns a `str`.

Comment: I would like the outcome was on the same line.

Comment: now I did: print('System'), self.checkStatus(), print('from SLEEP ARM'), but still last words are n the lower line

Comment: Possibly `self.checkStatus()` is printing something, rather than returning it - in which case you have no way to control it.

Comment: OMG you're right!!!! I have to change it to return.

Comment: Or, change that print statement to use `end=""`